# Postgresql Rails issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I need to convert an app from sqlite to Postgresql in order to use search with thinkingsphinx. I have run the following steps what am I missing?

I added the pg gem to my gemfile, ran brew install postgresql, and have configured my database.yml file as follows:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: example_development
  username: 
  password:
  host: localhost
  encoding: UTF8
```

I have also run the commands that homebrew suggests on installation:

```
If this is your first install, create a database with:
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres

If this is your first install, automatically load on login with:
mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgents
cp /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.4/org.postgresql.postgres.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.postgresql.postgres.plist
```

What do I put for my username and password? Is there a file I need to edit or do I need to create a database from the command line? There must be something simple that I am missing. I  haven't run any custom sql queries, and have stuck to active record defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the username and password of the account on the Postgres database you are using.

If you do not have a local postgres installation running, then there is no database to connect to, so you will have to follow some instructions online that outline installing and setting up a postgres database on your development machine.

Comment: I have a postgres installation running because I can check the version installed from my command line. I ran the commands that brew info postgresql shows. (link above) I think i have to run "createdb mydbname" in order to create a new database, and then I should link to that.

Comment: Depending on your system, there may or may not already be a 'postgres' user than you can use, then run the [createuser](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/app-createuser.html) command to make your own user.  Also, you can try using `postgres` as the user and password, I can't remember if that will work on a default installation or not.